# How to decrease a progress bar at the same time as the time on a time?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an application that will display the remaining time in each area(12 in total),

it needs to show the total of hours, minutes, and seconds as well as a decreasing progress bar that will reflect the time left in each area.

I've tried to make the progress bar decrease at the same time as the timer starts but it doesn't work.

also, the timer goes below 0 and it doesn't stop after the ClearInterval.

here's the  HTML:
`

```
<div class="peg-container-left">
  <div class="peg-name-1">
    <h3>Peg 1</h3>
  </div>

    <div class="peg-1-bar">
      <div class="peg-1-bar-fill">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="peg-name-2">
    <h3>Peg 2</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="peg-2-bar">
    <div class="peg-2-bar-fill ">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="peg-name-3">
    <h3>Peg 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-3-bar">
    <div class="peg-3-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-4">
    <h3>Peg 4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-4-bar">
    <div class="peg-4-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-5">
    <h3>Peg 5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-5-bar">
    <div class="peg-5-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-6">
    <h3>Peg 6</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-6-bar">
    <div class="peg-6-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="peg-container-left-timer">
  <div class="peg-1-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-1">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-2-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-2">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-3-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-3">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-4-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-4">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-5-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-5">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-6-timer">
  <span id="time-peg-6">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="peg-container-time-set">
  <div class="peg-1-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-1">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-2-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-2">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-3-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-3">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-4-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-4">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-5-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-5">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-6-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-6">00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="peg-container-right">
  <div class="peg-name-7">
    <h3>Peg 7</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-7-bar">
    <div class="peg-7-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-8">
    <h3>Peg 8</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-8-bar">
    <div class="peg-8-bar-fill">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-9">
    <h3>Peg 9</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="peg-9-bar">
    <div class="peg-9-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-10">
    <h3>Peg 10</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-10-bar">
    <div class="peg-10-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-11">
    <h3>Peg 11</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-11-bar">
    <div class="peg-11-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-12">
    <h3>Peg 12</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-12-bar">
    <div class="peg-12-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="peg-container-right-timer">
  <div class="peg-7-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-7">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-8-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-8">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-9-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-9">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-10-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-10">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-11-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-11">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-12-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-12">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="">
  <div class="peg-7-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-7">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-8-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-8">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-9-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-9">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-10-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-10">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-11-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-11">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-12-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-12">00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Here's the javascript:

`

```
const countPegOne = document.getElementById('time-peg-1');
const countPegTwo = document.getElementById('time-peg-2');
const countPegThree = document.getElementById('time-peg-3');
const countPegFour = document.getElementById('time-peg-4');
const countPegFive = document.getElementById('time-peg-5');
const countPegSix = document.getElementById('time-peg-6');
const countPegSeven = document.getElementById('time-peg-7');
const countPegEight = document.getElementById('time-peg-8');
const countPegNine = document.getElementById('time-peg-9');
const countPegTen = document.getElementById('time-peg-10');
const countPegEleven = document.getElementById('time-peg-11');
const countPegTwelve = document.getElementById('time-peg-12');
//Shows the bar fill.
const progressBarOne = document.getElementById('peg-1-bar-fill');
const progressBarTwo = document.getElementById('peg-2-bar-fill');
const progressBarThree = document.getElementById('peg-3-bar-fill');
const progressBarFour = document.getElementById('peg-4-bar-fill');
const progressBarFive = document.getElementById('peg-5-bar-fill');
const progressBarSix = document.getElementById('peg-6-bar-fill');
const progressBarSeven = document.getElementById('peg-7-bar-fill');
const progressBarEight = document.getElementById('peg-8-bar-fill');
const progressBarNine = document.getElementById('peg-9-bar-fill');
const progressBarTen = document.getElementById('peg-10-bar-fill');
const progressBarEleven = document.getElementById('peg-11-bar-fill');
const progressBarTwelve = document.getElementById('peg-12-bar-fill');
//sets the time of the peg
let startTimingPegOne = 0.1;
let startTimingPegTwo = 0.1;
let startTimingPegThree = 30;
let startTimingPegFour = 300;
let startTimingPegFive = 180;
let startTimingPegSix = 10;
let startTimingPegSeven = 20;
let startTimingPegEight = 30;
let startTimingPegNine = 40;
let startTimingPegTen = 50;
let startTimingPegEleven = 60;
let startTimingPegTwelve = 70;
// --------------------------------------

let timePegOne = startTimingPegOne * 60;
let timePegTwo = startTimingPegTwo * 60;
let timePegThree = startTimingPegThree * 60;
let timePegFour = startTimingPegFour * 60;
let timePegFive = startTimingPegFive * 60;
let timePegSix = startTimingPegSix * 60;
let timePegSeven = startTimingPegSeven * 60;
let timePegEight = startTimingPegEight * 60;
let timePegNine = startTimingPegNine * 60;
let timePegTen = startTimingPegTen * 60;
let timePegEleven = startTimingPegEleven * 60;
let timePegTwelve = startTimingPegTwelve * 60;

setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);

function updateTimer() {

  timePegOne--;
  timePegTwo--;
  timePegThree--;
  timePegFour--;
  timePegFive--;
  timePegSix--;
  timePegSeven--;
  timePegEight--;
  timePegNine--;
  timePegTen--;
  timePegEleven--;
  timePegTwelve--;


  const hoursPegOne = Math.floor((timePegOne / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegOne = Math.floor((timePegOne / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegOne = timePegOne % 60;

  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegOne = secondsPegOne < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegOne : secondsPegOne;
  minutesPegOne = minutesPegOne < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegOne : minutesPegOne;

  const hoursPegTwo = Math.floor((timePegTwo / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegTwo = Math.floor((timePegTwo / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegTwo = timePegTwo % 60;

  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegTwo = secondsPegTwo < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegTwo : secondsPegTwo;
  minutesPegTwo = minutesPegTwo < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegTwo : minutesPegTwo;


  const hoursPegThree = Math.floor((timePegThree / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegThree = Math.floor((timePegThree / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegThree = timePegThree % 60;

  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegThree = secondsPegThree < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegThree : secondsPegThree;
  minutesPegThree = minutesPegThree < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegThree : minutesPegThree;

  const hoursPegFour = Math.floor((timePegFour / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegFour = Math.floor((timePegFour / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegFour = timePegFour % 60;

  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegFour = secondsPegFour < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegFour : secondsPegFour;
  minutesPegFour = minutesPegFour < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegFour : minutesPegFour;

  const hoursPegFive = Math.floor((timePegFive / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegFive = Math.floor((timePegFive / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegFive = timePegFive % 60;

  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegFive = secondsPegFive < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegFive : secondsPegFive;
  minutesPegFive = minutesPegFive < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegFive : minutesPegFive;

  const hoursPegSix = Math.floor((timePegSix / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegSix = Math.floor((timePegSix / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegSix = timePegSix % 60;

  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegSix = secondsPegSix < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegSix : secondsPegSix;
  minutesPegSix = minutesPegSix < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegSix : minutesPegSix;


  const hoursPegSeven = Math.floor((timePegSeven / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegSeven = Math.floor((timePegSeven / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegSeven = timePegSeven % 60;

  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegSeven = secondsPegSeven < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegSeven : secondsPegSeven;
  minutesPegSeven = minutesPegSeven < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegSeven : minutesPegSeven;

  const hoursPegEight = Math.floor((timePegEight / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegEight = Math.floor((timePegEight / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegEight = timePegEight % 60;

  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegEight = secondsPegEight < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegEight : secondsPegEight;
  minutesPegEight = minutesPegEight < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegEight : minutesPegEight;

  const hoursPegNine = Math.floor((timePegNine / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegNine = Math.floor((timePegNine / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegNine = timePegNine % 60;
  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegNine = secondsPegNine < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegNine : secondsPegNine;
  minutesPegNine = minutesPegNine < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegNine : minutesPegNine;

  const hoursPegTen = Math.floor((timePegTen / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegTen = Math.floor((timePegTen / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegTen = timePegTen % 60;
  // when less than 10 add 0 before number
  secondsPegTen = secondsPegTen < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegTen : secondsPegTen;
  minutesPegTen = minutesPegTen < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegTen : minutesPegTen;

  const hoursPegEleven = Math.floor((timePegEleven / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegEleven = Math.floor((timePegEleven / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegEleven = timePegEleven % 60;
  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegEleven = secondsPegEleven < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegEleven : secondsPegEleven;
  minutesPegEleven = minutesPegEleven < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegEleven : minutesPegEleven;

  const hoursPegTwelve = Math.floor((timePegTwelve / (60 * 60)));
  let minutesPegTwelve = Math.floor((timePegTwelve / 60) % 60);
  let secondsPegTwelve = timePegTwelve % 60;
  // when less than 10 add 0 before number

  secondsPegTwelve = secondsPegTwelve < 10 ? '0' + secondsPegTwelve : secondsPegTwelve;
  minutesPegTwelve = minutesPegTwelve < 10 ? '0' + minutesPegTwelve : minutesPegTwelve;



  let progressWidthOne = (startTimingPegOne / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthTwo = (startTimingPegTwo / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthThree = (startTimingPegThree / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthFour = (startTimingPegFour / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthFive = (startTimingPegFive / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthSix = (startTimingPegSix / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthSeven = (startTimingPegSeven / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthEight = (startTimingPegEight / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthNine = (startTimingPegNine / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthTen = (startTimingPegTen / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthEleven = (startTimingPegEleven / 10) * 100;
  let progressWidthTwelve = (startTimingPegTwelve / 10) * 100;

  countPegOne.innerHTML = `${hoursPegOne}:${minutesPegOne}:${secondsPegOne}`;
  countPegTwo.innerHTML = `${hoursPegTwo}:${minutesPegTwo}:${secondsPegTwo}`;
  countPegThree.innerHTML = `${hoursPegThree}:${minutesPegThree}:${secondsPegThree}`;
  countPegFour.innerHTML = `${hoursPegFour}:${minutesPegFour}:${secondsPegFour}`;
  countPegFive.innerHTML = `${hoursPegFive}:${minutesPegFive}:${secondsPegFive}`;
  countPegSix.innerHTML = `${hoursPegSix}:${minutesPegSix}:${secondsPegSix}`;
  countPegSeven.innerHTML = `${hoursPegSeven}:${minutesPegSeven}:${secondsPegSeven}`;
  countPegEight.innerHTML = `${hoursPegEight}:${minutesPegEight}:${secondsPegEight}`;
  countPegNine.innerHTML = `${hoursPegNine}:${minutesPegNine}:${secondsPegNine}`;
  countPegTen.innerHTML = `${hoursPegTen}:${minutesPegTen}:${secondsPegTen}`;
  countPegEleven.innerHTML = `${hoursPegEleven}:${minutesPegEleven}:${secondsPegEleven}`;
  countPegTwelve.innerHTML = `${hoursPegTwelve}:${minutesPegTwelve}:${secondsPegTwelve}`;


  if (hoursPegOne <= 0 && minutesPegOne <= 0 && secondsPegOne <= 00) {

    countPegOne.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegtwo.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegOThree.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegFour.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegFive.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegSix.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegSeven.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegEight.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegNine.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegTen.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegEleven.innerHTML = "Game over";
    countPegTwelve.innerHTML = "Game over";
    clearInterval((timePegone = 0));

  } else if (timePegOne > 0 && timePegTwo > 0 && timePegThree > 0 && timePegFour > 0
    && timePegFive > 0 && timePegSix > 0 && timePegSeven > 0 && timePegEight > 0
    && timePegNine > 0 && timePegTen > 0 && timePegEleven > 0 && timePegEleven > 0 && timePegTwelve > 0) {

    progressBarOne.style.width = progressWidthOne + "%";

    progressBarTwo.style.width = progressWidthTwo + "%";

    progressBarThree.style.width = progressWidthThree + "%";

    progressBarFour.style.width = progressWidthFour + "%";

    progressBarFive.style.width = progressWidthFive + "%";

    progressBarSix.style.width = progressWidthSix + "%";

    progressBarSeven.style.width = progressWidthSeven + "%";

    progressBarEight.style.width = progressWidthEight + "%";

    progressBarNine.style.width = progressWidthNine + "%";

    progressBarTen.style.width = progressWidthTen + "%";

    progressBarEleven.style.width = progressWidthEleven + "%";

    progressBarTwelve.style.width = progressWidthTwelve + "%";

    checkColors(progressWidthOne);

  } else {
    progressBarOne.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarTwo.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarThree.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarFour.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarFive.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarSix.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarSeven.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarEight.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarNine.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarTen.style.width = "0%";
    progressBarTwelve.style.width = "0%";
  }

};

const checkColors = (width) => {
  if (width > 60) {
    progressBarOne.style.background = "Green"
  } else if (width > 30) {
    progressBarOne.style.background = "orange";
  } else {
    progressBarOne.style.background = "red";
  }
};

`
```

I am out of ideas, any help?

Comment: The interval does not stop because [clearInterval(intervalID)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) requires an id returned by [setInterval(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: For clearing the interval, the interval variable has to be declared then used: **let _timer =setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);** then **clearInterval(_timer);**

Comment: Does that mean I have to create an interval for the 12 timers in order to make them stop?

Comment: In your code you call `setInterval` once, so a single `clearInterval` is enough, but you have to store the value (the interval ID) that `setInterval` returns when you call it and pass that same value when calling `clearInterval`. See imvain2 comment, that's the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I run your code and in addition to the timer/interval not stopping, also some errors show up in the console. That is problematic because when an error happens the code that follows (the code after the point in code where the error happens) will not be executed. So you have to take care of those errors first, otherwise you might be making changes to a part of your code that is never executed and wondering why the changes have no effect.

There are two distinct errors showing up in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
Uncaught ReferenceError: countPegtwo is not defined"
```

Let's focus on the 2nd error first. An "Uncaught ReferenceError:  is not defined" means that you are trying to access a reference that does not exist in the scope where you are trying to access it. In your case, the spelling (letter casing) of the reference is wrong. It should be `countPegTwo` with a capital T. If we fix that in code on this line

```js
countPegTwo.innerHTML = "Game over";
```

and run the code again, we still get two distinct errors in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
Uncaught ReferenceError: countPegOThree is not defined"
```

Another reference is misspelled. We fix that one as well

```js
countPegThree.innerHTML = "Game over";
```

If we run the code again we are left with just one distinct error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
```

This error is letting you know that the code is trying to read the property `style` on a `null` type/value/reference.
That happens on lines such as this one:

```
progressBarOne.style.width = progressWidthOne + "%";
```

But why is `progressBarOne` `null` here?
Let's check where it is last assigned. Last assignment is on this line:

```
const progressBarOne = document.getElementById('peg-1-bar-fill');
```

Thats the only assignment, `const` gives you that guarantee, so use `const` over `let` as much as possible. It makes code easier to reason about.

Why does `document.getElementById('peg-1-bar-fill');` return `null` here?
If we check the HTML it turns out that the string `peg-1-bar-fill` is only used as a class name and there is no element with such id.
There are a few possible fixes here:

1. we could query the class name instead of the id
2. we could add the missing `id="peg-1-bar-fill"` and repeat the same fix on all similar HTML elements that are missing their own id
3. we could replace `class="peg-1-bar-fill"` with `id="peg-1-bar-fill"` but then styles (if you have any) would have to be fixed as well.

Since it turns out we need to fix this for all 12 progress bars, the way of least typing is to go with solution 1, since it is in one place in code and it won't mess with any styles.

In code instead of calling `document.getElementById('peg-1-bar-fill');` we call `document.querySelector('.peg-1-bar-fill');`. With that we are instructing JS to query a selector (instead of looking for an id). The selector we specify is a class name, because we prefix it with a dot `.` (a dot in CSS selectors means we want to select a class name). See also [Finding the first element matching a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#finding_the_first_element_matching_a_class)

We do that for all 12 elements so the new code is

```
//Shows the bar fill.
const progressBarOne = document.querySelector('.peg-1-bar-fill');
const progressBarTwo = document.querySelector('.peg-2-bar-fill');
const progressBarThree = document.querySelector('.peg-3-bar-fill');
const progressBarFour = document.querySelector('.peg-4-bar-fill');
const progressBarFive = document.querySelector('.peg-5-bar-fill');
const progressBarSix = document.querySelector('.peg-6-bar-fill');
const progressBarSeven = document.querySelector('.peg-7-bar-fill');
const progressBarEight = document.querySelector('.peg-8-bar-fill');
const progressBarNine = document.querySelector('.peg-9-bar-fill');
const progressBarTen = document.querySelector('.peg-10-bar-fill');
const progressBarEleven = document.querySelector('.peg-11-bar-fill');
const progressBarTwelve = document.querySelector('.peg-12-bar-fill');
```

If we run the code again we get no errors in the console. So now we are left with the problem of the interval not stopping.

The interval does not stop because the call `clearInterval(...)` requires an id returned by `setInterval(...)`. See the documentation to learn how these work in tandem

- [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)
- [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

It is similar to [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout).

The docs for `setInterval` say:

> The returned intervalID is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to setInterval(); this value can be passed to clearInterval() to cancel the interval.
>
> It may be helpful to be aware that setInterval() and setTimeout() share the same pool of IDs, and that clearInterval() and clearTimeout() can technically be used interchangeably. For clarity, however, you should try to always match them to avoid confusion when maintaining your code.

That means we just need to keep a reference to the value retuned by `setInterval` and then pass that value to `clearInterval`. So we change this line

```
const intervalId = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

and this line (here we also put the assignment as a separate line and fix the spelling).

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
timePegOne = 0;
```

If we run the code again, this now stops the interval. However, since all your timer logic is in a single callback, this stops all the timers, which might or might not be what you were trying to do.

If that's not the intended behaviour then the logic in the `if/else if` checks would have to be changed to affect the behaviour of the current code.

---

## How to reduce the repeated code

There is a lot of repetition in your code since every bit of logic is repeated for each of the 12 timers/pegs.
That makes it harder to make the same changes in logic for all elements in one place and it also makes it harder to add new functionality. What if there were 100 elements?

The logic can be moved into a function (+ helper functions) and then those functions can be called in a loop for each of the timers/pegs.

There are of course many ways to approach this, but here is one suggestion.
The code repeated 12 times such as this

```js
const countPegOne = document.getElementById('time-peg-1');
...
const progressBarOne = document.querySelector('.peg-1-bar-fill');
...
let startTimingPegOne = 0.1;
...
let timePegOne = startTimingPegOne * 60;
```

Can be put into a function that takes some parameters and returns an object with helper functions to invoke the logic and with other necessary data and references.

```js
function createPeg(name, startTimeInSeconds) {
  // shows the progress bar
  const uiProgressBar = document.querySelector(`.${name}-bar-fill`);
  // shows the current time
  const uiTime = document.getElementById(`time-${name}`);
  // shows the starting time
  const uiStartTime = document.querySelector(`.${name}-start-time > span`);

  let currentTimeInSeconds = startTimeInSeconds

  // returns the current time
  function getTime() {
    return currentTimeInSeconds;
  }

  // sets the new time
  function setTime(newTimeInSeconds) {
    if (newTimeInSeconds < 0) newTimeInSeconds = 0;

    currentTimeInSeconds = newTimeInSeconds;
  }

  // return an object that contains the getter and setter, the start time value and all UI references
  return {
    getTime: getTime,
    setTime: setTime,
    startTimeInSeconds: startTimeInSeconds,
    ui: {
      progressBar: uiProgressBar,
      time: uiTime,
      startTime: uiStartTime
    }
  }
}
```

This function can then be called to instantiate each element. The returned objects can even be added to an array to make it easier to loop over all of them at once.

```js
const allPegs = [
  createPeg('peg-1', 6),        //  6 seconds
  createPeg('peg-2', 0.1 * 60), //  6 seconds
  createPeg('peg-3', 10),       // 10 seconds
  // ...
  createPeg('peg-12', 70 * 60), // 70 minutes
];
```

The other logic can either be moved into the `setTime` function or all calculations could still be done elsewhere in code and then calls to `getTime/setTime` could be used to store the new time.

Here is one way to do the whole logic as part of the `setTime` call.

```js
  // sets the time and updates the related UI
  function setTime(newTimeInSeconds) {
    if (newTimeInSeconds < 0) newTimeInSeconds = 0;
    
    currentTimeInSeconds = newTimeInSeconds;
    
    uiTime.innerHTML = formatTime(currentTimeInSeconds);
    
    // updates the width and the background color of the progress bar
    const percent = (currentTimeInSeconds / startTimeInSeconds) * 100;    
    uiProgressBar.style.width = `${percent}%`;
    if (percent > 60) {
      uiProgressBar.style.background = "green";
      } else if (percent > 30) {
        uiProgressBar.style.background = "orange";
    } else {
        uiProgressBar.style.background = "red";
    }
  }

  // formats the time as hh:mm:ss
  function formatTime(timeInSeconds) {
    const hours = Math.floor(timeInSeconds / (60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((timeInSeconds / 60) % 60);
    let seconds = Math.ceil(timeInSeconds % 60);
    
    // when less than 10 add 0 before number
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
         
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }

  // initialize with the start time
  uiStartTime.innerHTML = formatTime(startTimeInSeconds);
  setTime(startTimeInSeconds);
```

With the above in place, then the setTime can be called in a for loop for all elements.

```js
function updateTimer() {
  for (const peg of allPegs) {
    const time = peg.getTime() 
    if (time > 0) {
        peg.setTime(time - 1);
      if (peg.getTime() === 0) {
        peg.ui.time.innerHTML = "Game over"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the stop condition for the interval can be also checked across all elements with a simple call to `allPegs.every(peg => ...)` or `allPegs.some(peg => ...)` depending on what kind of stopping logic you would like to have.

```js
function updateTimer() {
  //...
  
  // the stop condition
  // stop the interval when time on every peg reaches 0
  // if you want the interval to stop when the first peg reaches 0
  // then replace .every with .some
  if (allPegs.every(peg => peg.getTime() === 0)) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}
```

Here is the whole example in a code snippet. Press the "Run code snippet" button to see it in action.

```js
function createPeg(name, startTimeInSeconds) {
  // shows the progress bar
  const uiProgressBar = document.querySelector(`.${name}-bar-fill`);
   // shows the current time
  const uiTime = document.getElementById(`time-${name}`);
  // shows the starting time
  const uiStartTime = document.querySelector(`.${name}-start-time > span`);
  
  let currentTimeInSeconds = 0;
  
  // returns the current time
  function getTime() {
    return currentTimeInSeconds;
  }
  
  // sets the time and updates the related UI
  function setTime(newTimeInSeconds) {
    if (newTimeInSeconds < 0) newTimeInSeconds = 0;
    
    currentTimeInSeconds = newTimeInSeconds;
    
    uiTime.innerHTML = formatTime(currentTimeInSeconds);
    
    // updates the width and the background color of the progress bar
    const percent = (currentTimeInSeconds / startTimeInSeconds) * 100;    
    uiProgressBar.style.width = `${percent}%`;
    if (percent > 60) {
      uiProgressBar.style.background = "green";
      } else if (percent > 30) {
        uiProgressBar.style.background = "orange";
    } else {
        uiProgressBar.style.background = "red";
    }
  }    
  
  // formats the time as hh:mm:ss
  function formatTime(timeInSeconds) {
    const hours = Math.floor(timeInSeconds / (60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((timeInSeconds / 60) % 60);
    let seconds = Math.ceil(timeInSeconds % 60);
    
    // when less than 10 add 0 before number
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
         
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }
  
  // initialize with the start time
  uiStartTime.innerHTML = formatTime(startTimeInSeconds);
  setTime(startTimeInSeconds);
  
  // return an object that contains the getter and setter for time, the start time value and all UI references
  return {
    getTime: getTime,
    setTime: setTime,
    startTimeInSeconds: startTimeInSeconds,
    ui: {
      progressBar: uiProgressBar,
      time: uiTime,
      startTime: uiStartTime
    }
  }
}

const allPegs = [
  createPeg('peg-1', 6),            //  6 seconds
  createPeg('peg-2', 0.1 * 60),     //  6 seconds
  createPeg('peg-3', 10),           // 10 seconds
  //createPeg('peg-4', 300 * 60),   // 300 minutes
  //createPeg('peg-5', 180 * 60),
  //createPeg('peg-6', 10 * 60),                    
  //createPeg('peg-7', 20 * 60),
  //createPeg('peg-8', 30 * 60),
  //createPeg('peg-9', 40 * 60),
  //createPeg('peg-10', 50 * 60),
  //createPeg('peg-11', 60 * 60),
  //createPeg('peg-12', 70 * 60), // 70 minutes
];

const elapsedSecondsPerInterval = 1; // now it works with 0.1 or 0.05 as well
const intervalId = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000 * elapsedSecondsPerInterval);

function updateTimer() {
  for (const peg of allPegs) {
    const time = peg.getTime() 
    if (time > 0) {
        peg.setTime(time - elapsedSecondsPerInterval);
      if (peg.getTime() === 0) {
        peg.ui.time.innerHTML = "Game over"
      }
    }
  }
  
  // the stop condition
  // stop the interval when the time on every peg reaches 0
  // if you want the interval to stop when the first peg reaches 0 then replace .every with .some
  if (allPegs.every(peg => peg.getTime() === 0)) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}
```

```css
div[class*=bar-fill] {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="peg-container-left">
  <div class="peg-name-1">
    <h3>Peg 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-1-bar">
    <div class="peg-1-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="peg-name-2">
    <h3>Peg 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-2-bar">
    <div class="peg-2-bar-fill ">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="peg-name-3">
    <h3>Peg 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-3-bar">
    <div class="peg-3-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="peg-name-4">
    <h3>Peg 4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-4-bar">
    <div class="peg-4-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="peg-name-5">
    <h3>Peg 5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-5-bar">
    <div class="peg-5-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="peg-name-6">
    <h3>Peg 6</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-6-bar">
    <div class="peg-6-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="peg-container-left-timer">
  <div class="peg-1-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-1">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-2-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-2">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-3-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-3">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-4-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-4">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-5-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-5">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-6-timer">
  <span id="time-peg-6">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="peg-container-time-set">
  <div class="peg-1-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-1">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-2-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-2">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-3-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-3">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-4-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-4">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-5-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-5">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-6-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-6">00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="peg-container-right">
  <div class="peg-name-7">
    <h3>Peg 7</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-7-bar">
    <div class="peg-7-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-8">
    <h3>Peg 8</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-8-bar">
    <div class="peg-8-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-9">
    <h3>Peg 9</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-9-bar">
    <div class="peg-9-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-10">
    <h3>Peg 10</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-10-bar">
    <div class="peg-10-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-11">
    <h3>Peg 11</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-11-bar">
    <div class="peg-11-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-name-12">
    <h3>Peg 12</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-12-bar">
    <div class="peg-12-bar-fill">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="peg-container-right-timer">
  <div class="peg-7-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-7">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-8-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-8">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-9-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-9">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-10-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-10">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-11-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-11">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-12-timer">
    <span id="time-peg-12">0:00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="">
  <div class="peg-7-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-7">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-8-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-8">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-9-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-9">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-10-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-10">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-11-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-11">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="peg-12-start-time">
    <span id="total-time-12">00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dam this is too long